# Java servlet - get list of local printers

Tags: java, servlets, printers

How we can get list of local pc printers by java servlet running on other machine.

The web application running on Development server, i want to read the list of printer where the application is accessing.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlets cannot directly access local network. If you want to identify them you will need another program which can communicate with your local printers. You might need to write a simple printer identification [program](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html) and then let that data access to your servlets. Other than this there is no way you can directly interact with printers with servlets.

Comment: Could you please let me know how can we call applet inside servlet.
How can we initialize applet using servlet.

Comment: @YugandharGali, you cannot directly invoke as I know but you need to check that. But definitely your printer program can update a db table periodically and from that you can access the table from servlet.

Comment: @Silva, Thanks for reply.

The problem is i dont know the client machine, which will access the application.

If can initialize the applet on servlet access will get list of printer on  client. Here is the challenge.

How the printer program auto initializes to store printers in DB.

Comment: @YugandharGali, So you are saying that you dont have access to your local computers..? then this solution is not the thing you need to apply